# How to check if text1 contains text2 using vb6?

Tags: vb6

How to check if text1 contains text2 using vb6 ?

```
Dim text1 as string
Dim text2 as string

text1 = "hello world I am Anas"
text2 = "Anas"

if (check if text2 is in text1) 'the result should be true or false
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [`InStr`](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/instr.html#syntax) function like this:

```
Dim position As Integer

position = InStr(1, stringToSearch, stringToFind)

If position > 0 Then
  ' text is inside
Else
  ' text is not inide 
End If
```

Answer (score 17):

Use [`InStr`](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions):

```
If InStr(text1, text2) > 0 Then
```

Comment: +1 but why not link to the VB6 manual entry for Instr  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445031(v=VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
if (InStr(text1, text2) > 0)
```

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.80).aspx for special cases (parameters are Nothing, empty strings etc.)

Comment: You are linking to vb.net, not vb6.

Answer (score 2):

```
RTM = InStr(1, text1,text2)

if RTM > 0 then debug.print "Text2 was found at position: "; RTM
```